# Window resize causes background to cover rest of page

Tags: html, css, background, resize, window

I am creating a webpage with CSS and HTML and I stumbled upon an annoying issue. When I resize my browser window, the background color covers the part of the page that is out of view, on the right side. It sounds a little vague but luckily, I have found a webpage on which this occurs also, [here](http://templated.co/grassygrass). Dragging the browser window to the left or right of the screen (Win 7 and 8) will resize the page, and when you look at the off-screen part of the page, you can see that it's "covered" with the background color.

I have tried searching the web for a solution to this issue but I find it hard to come up with an effective search term. Hopefully someone here can help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a "max-width" to the .container, like so (includes current code):

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 100%; //this is the new line
}
```

*(.container is found in default.css on line 212.)*

Comment: Thanks! This solves the background issue, but now some `div` tags will move to a different position so they fit the page. And now horizontal scrolling is not possible anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't really want horizontal scrolling possible - it's not a great user experience. I'd advise changing the CSS rules on the items inside the container so they are either percentage (and nicely respond when you change the window), or use media queries.